# if statement doesn't work in a razor page

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor page in which I want to display certain text if the value of the ViewData["IsActive"] is true.
I'm not getting any text.

```
<div class="page-login-block-info big centered">
@if (ViewData["IsActive"])
{
    <h2>text 1</h2>
}
else
{
    <h2>text 2</h2>
}
</div>
```

I tried writing @{ if statement here } but still doesn't work.

I know for sure that ViewData["IsActive"] returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try :

```
<div class="page-login-block-info big centered">
@if ((bool)ViewData["IsActive"]==true)
{
    <h2>text 1</h2>
}
else
{
    <h2>text 2</h2>
}
</div>
```